# What's wrong with Skype group - they are not saved in my account?

Tags: skype, address-book

The Skype groups in my office all disappear when I open Skype at home. What's wrong? Why Skype not store them as a contact? This is annoying indeed or I am missing something. What do you think?

Comment: Do you have the same Skype versions installed?

Is "Show Contact Groups" selected in both of them?

Comment: @rems: Of course all my Skype version are the latest.